# Post being duplicated with foreach loop

Tags: posts, loop, options

I am trying to create posts from options in the database, but I am getting duplicates of the posts each time I run the function even though I have added a conditional to check for duplicates.

Here is my code

```
function create_post_from_option() {
    global $wpdb;
    $query_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'options';
    $options = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT option_name, option_value FROM $query_name WHERE option_name LIKE 'city_%'");
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($options as $key => $row) {
        $title = 'City Of' . ' ' .  $city_name_scraped ;
        $url = $row->option_value;
        $city_name = $row->option_name;
        $city_name_scraped = substr($city_name, 5);
        if (!get_page_by_title($title,' OBJECT', 'cities') ){

            $post_args = array(
                'post_author' =>'',
                'post_content' => 'City Of' . ' ' . $city_name_scraped,
                'post_content_filtered' => 'City Of'. ' ' .  $city_name_scraped,
                'post_title' => 'City Of' . ' ' .  $city_name_scraped ,
                'post_excerpt' =>  'City Of' . ' ' .  $city_name_scraped,
                'post_status' =>  'publish',
                'post_type' =>  'cities',
                'comment_status' =>  '',
                'ping_status' =>  '',
                'meta_input' => array(
                    'featured_image' => $post_image,
                )
            );

            wp_insert_post($post_args, $wp_error);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You use `$city_name_scraped` before you set it.

Comment: You rock! I can't believe I overlooked that!